# WixBA doesn't show any .NET Framework installed

Tags: c#, wix, bootstrapper, burn

Experimentally, I simply copied WixBA project from WiX 3.7 source, replaced the reference from core.csproj to BootstrapperCore and tried to use it with my own Bundle which is working fine with my own Manged Bootstrapper. It built fine. But strangely, when I tried to run it, it showed me the dialog to install [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) framework. And I already have .NET framework 4.5 installed. I even tried with changing the WixBA's Targetframework to 4.5, but it resulted in the same thing.

Why is that so? Is there any security technique used, so that no other Bundle can be used with it?
If yes, what is the explanation?

Comment: Can you post the content of your Wix `<Bundle>` tag, as well as the `<startup>` and `<wix.bootstrapper>` tags in your BootstrapperCore.config file?

Answer (score 1):

The [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) installer dialog is based on the version of the .NET installer bundled with the installer. Take a look at your `Bundle.wxs` file and look for one of the [WiX-provided Package groups](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html) in the `Chain` tag. It likely looks something like this:

```
<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Web"/>
```

There are a couple of possibilities as to why it's prompting you even though you've already installed .NET 4.5:

1) The PackageGroupRef is for a different version of .NET (v4.0, for example) than what you have installed.
2) The version you have installed is the "Client" version of .NET, instead of the "Full" version, which is used by the installer.

You'll also need to make sure the version of the PackageGroupRef matches the `supportedRuntime` entries in your `BootstrapperCore.config` file of your managed bootstrapper project, as well as the `supportedFramework` in the `wix.bootstrapper` tag:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
</startup>

<wix.bootstrapper>
  <host assemblyName="MyInstallerUI">
    <supportedFramework version="v4\Full" />
  </host>
</wix.bootstrapper>
```

Comment: Actually, my Burn.wxs is part of my own Managed Bootstrapper (for which I'm fighting with its upgrade methodology). And when same is used with WixBA, its behavior is different. I was interested to see if I use Wix's installer's interface.

Comment: However, my working MBA is .Net 2.0 based, while WixBA is .Net 4.0 based. But as I have 4.5 installed as well, this behavior is unexpected.